# How to handle text tables with FastParse?

Tags: parsing, fastparse

I have text file with single row table (tab separated) and I need to parse it to receive Map("one" -> 1, "two" -> 2, "three" -> 3). I can't figure out how to do it and even not sure that it is possible at all. Any ideas guys?

```
one two three
1   2   3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've figured out how to do it by myself.

```
val lines = Source.fromResource("test.txt").getLines().mkString("\r\n")

  def sentence[_: P] = P(CharIn("0-9", "a-z").rep(1).!)

  def tableHeader[_: P] = P((sentence.! ~ "\t".?).rep ~ lineSeparator)
  def tableRow[_: P](h: Seq[String]) = P((sentence.! ~ "\t".?).rep ~ (lineSeparator | End))
    .map(r => println(h.zip(r).toMap))
  def singleRowTable[_: P] = P(tableHeader.flatMap(tableRow))
  def lineSeparator[_: P] = P("\r\n" | "\r" | "\n")
  def parseA[_: P] = P(singleRowTable)


  parse(lines, parseA(_), true) match {
    case Parsed.Success(value, successIndex) =>
      println("Success value=" + value +" successIndex=" + successIndex)
    case f @ Parsed.Failure(label, index, extra) =>
      println("Failure " + f.trace(true))

  }
```

It will print

```
Map(one -> 1, two -> 2, three -> 3)
Success value=() successIndex=20
```